# Importing Sea Surface Temperature text files in ASCII format into R

Tags: r, time-series, bigdata, temperature

I have downloaded multiple .txt.gz files for [Hadley Sea Surface Temperature observations](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadisst/data/download.html). The data have been unzipped, resulting in mutiple .txt files in [ASCII format](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadisst/data/Read_instructions_sst.txt).
I have the following files (the R script is the one I'm working on):

```
list.files()
 [1] "Get_SST_Data.R"                "HadISST1_SST_1931-1960.txt"    "HadISST1_SST_1931-1960.txt.gz"
 [4] "HadISST1_SST_1961-1990.txt"    "HadISST1_SST_1961-1990.txt.gz" "HadISST1_SST_1991-2003.txt"   
 [7] "HadISST1_SST_2004.txt"         "HadISST1_SST_2005.txt"         "HadISST1_SST_2006.txt"        
[10] "HadISST1_SST_2007.txt"         "HadISST1_SST_2008.txt"         "HadISST1_SST_2009.txt"        
[13] "HadISST1_SST_2010.txt"         "HadISST1_SST_2011.txt"         "HadISST1_SST_2012.txt"        
[16] "HadISST1_SST_2013.txt"
```

I would like to be able to utilize the temperature data to make a numeric vector for the Sea Surface Temperature for everyday since 1950, to eventually make a time series plot.

Which will look something like this

[image]

**[p.s. this is just for reference...]**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To look something like [this](http://processtrends.com/images/RClimate_GISS_trend_latest.png).

Comment: I have added image which you mentioned in above comment in your question itself...

Comment: Thanks @vrajs5, I couldn't work that out

Comment: Btw your problem is to create a chart or import multiple files? In any case similar questions are already answered...

Comment: No, the end result is to use a temperature variable in a model. I'm just not sure how to organise the data into a meaningful format. The ASCII data just seems to be unreadable. I have imported the files, no problem

Comment: Those data don't seem to be daily... they're monthly means as far as I can tell (see my solution below). Maybe the NetCDF data are daily.

Answer (score 3):

**[Edit: Tested only on Linux]**

R is able to read NetCDF format (http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadisst/data/HadISST_sst.nc.gz). You can use the "raster" package to read these data, after decompression, such as:

```
library(raster)
library(xts)
library(caTools)
```

Some time definitions:

```
startYear <- 1950   # start of the period
endYear <- 2011     # end of the period
subp <- '1951-01-01/1980-12-01'   # period for the climatology calculation
```

Open the file:

```
sst <- brick('HadISST_sst.nc')
Date <- substr(names(sst),2,11) 
Date <- gsub('\\.', '\\-', Date)
Date <- as.Date(Date)
dstart <- paste(startYear,'01','01',sep='-'); dstart <- grep(dstart, Date)
dend <- paste(endYear,'12','01',sep='-'); dend <- grep(dend, Date)
sst <- subset(sst, dstart:dend)
Date <- Date[dstart:dend]
```

Extract the time serie for a specific point (lat=35, lon=120):

```
tserie <- as.vector(extract(sst, cbind(116, -35)))
tserie <- xts(tserie, order.by=Date)
```

Calculate the climatology for the subp period:

```
clim <- as.numeric()
for(ii in 1:12){
  clim[ii] <- mean(tserie[subp][(.indexmon(tserie[subp])+1) == ii])
}
clim <- xts(rep(clim, length(tserie)/12), order.by=Date)
```

Calculate anomalies:

```
tserie <- tserie - clim
```

Plot the result:

```
par(las=1)
plot(tserie, t='n', main='HadISST')
lines(tserie, col='grey')
lines(xts(runmean(tserie, 12), order.by=Date), col='red', lwd=2)
legend('bottomleft', c('Monthly anomaly','12-month moving avg'), lty=c(1,1), lwd=c(1,2), col=c('grey','red'))
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what is in the sst matrix variable

Comment: This looks great @Pascal - I'm running into a bit of trouble however with the  

`dstart <- grep(dstart, Date)
dend <- grep(dend, Date)` commands. They seem to be making empty integers - which is resulting in the error  `Error in dstart:dend : argument of length 0`   when running `sst <- subset(sst, dstart:dend)`

Comment: I don't get this error. Did you set `startYear` and `endYear`?

Comment: Yeah I did. What happens is the first dstart / dend sets the date,  then the grep overwrites it as anew empty numeric variable

Comment: It works fine for me. With the example, `dstart` gives `961` and `dend` gives `1704`.

Comment: I can't get it to work - its still showing the variable as an empty integer. Am I missing a package?

Comment: Probably the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`NetCDF` is definitely a better way to go since the format of the ascii data is pretty horrible. That said, here's a function that reads in the data you have downloaded.

```
read.things <- function(f) {
  # f is the file path of your ascii data
  require(raster)
  d <- readLines(f)
  d <- split(d, rep(1:12, each=181))
  d <- lapply(d, function(x) read.fwf(textConnection(x), rep(6, 360), 
                                      skip=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                                      na.strings=c(-1000, -32768)))
  d <- lapply(d, function(x) sapply(x, as.numeric))
  out <- stack(lapply(d, raster))
  names(out) <- month.abb
  extent(out) <- c(-180, 180, -90, 90)
  out/100
}
```

Note that I've set 100% ice cells (`-100`) and land cells (`-32768`) as `NA`.

Below, we download one of the files (1Mb) as an example:

```
download.file(
  'http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadisst/data/HadISST1_SST_2004.txt.gz',
  destfile= {f <- tempfile()})

s <- read.things(f)

s

# class       : RasterBrick 
# dimensions  : 180, 360, 64800, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
# resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
# extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
# data source : in memory
# names       :   Jan,   Feb,   Mar,   Apr,   May,   Jun,   Jul,   Aug,   Sep,   Oct,   Nov,   Dec 
# min values  :   -10,   -10,   -10,   -10,   -10,   -10,   -10,   -10,   -10,   -10,   -10,   -10 
# max values  : 30.34, 30.58, 30.43, 30.50, 30.83, 31.39, 32.71, 33.40, 32.61, 31.52, 30.60, 30.51 

library(rasterVis)
levelplot(s, at=seq(min(s[], na.rm=T), max(s[], na.rm=T), len=100),
          col.regions=colorRampPalette(c('#2c7bb6', '#abd9e9', '#ffffbf', 
                                         '#fdae61', '#d7191c')))
```

[image]

Comment: This is lovely! However, I should have clarified - I only want the temperature data for a specific area (lat = 35, long = 116) for the last 60 years. The desired outcome is something like a time/date variable aligned with the temperature. I'm using the sea surface temperature in comparison with a time series.   Beautiful plot though

Comment: @eboylen I assume you mean lat = -35, because otherwise you're in a land cell in China (and I noticed you're from WA). Regardless, once you've got a `rasterStack`, you can do something like: `s[cellFromXY(s, c(116, -35))]`, which returns the monthly SST for the grid cell that includes that point.

Comment: Thanks @jbaums, this works for the data sets which only have 1 year's worth of data. However, there are three data sets which have 30 years of data for example the HadISST1_SST_1931-1960.txt.gz - any advice how to deal with these data sets?

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because if you look at the structure of the dates they always go from the 16th to the 16th. If you replace:

```
dstart <- paste(startYear,'01','01',sep='-'); dstart <- grep(dstart, Date)
dend <- paste(endYear,'12','01',sep='-'); dend <- grep(dend, Date)
```

for,

```
dstart <- paste(startYear,'01','16',sep='-'); dstart <- grep(dstart, Date)
dend <- paste(endYear,'12','16',sep='-'); dend <- grep(dend, Date)
```

It will work.